# Easy way to clean up un-staged deleted files in Git

Tags: git

Often I move files in a git repository using my IDE or via the command line (not via git mv).

As a result I and end up with several unstaged files to be deleted on my next commit as below:

```
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   test.html
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   deleted:    css/bootstrap.css
#   deleted:    css/bootstrap.min.css
#   deleted:    img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png
#   deleted:    img/glyphicons-halflings.png
#   deleted:    js/bootstrap.js
#   deleted:    js/bootstrap.min.js
```

I typically will select all the deleted files and edit them in a text editor to produce like:

```
git rm  css/bootstrap.css
git rm  css/bootstrap.min.css
git rm  img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png
git rm  img/glyphicons-halflings.png
git rm  js/bootstrap.js
git rm  js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Which I then throw back into the console.

Is there a way to do this without having to copy/paste?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to commit your deletes...that is, you want to perform the equivalent of `git rm` for *all* of the files that show up as deleted.  `git clean` won't do this.

You can run `git add -u`:

> Only match  against already tracked files in the index
>   rather than  the working tree. That means that it will never stage new
>   files, but that it will stage modified new contents of tracked files
>   and that it will remove files from the index if the corresponding
>   files in the working tree have been removed.

This will pick up all changes to tracked files, including deletes.  So if you start with this:

```
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   deleted:    file2
#   deleted:    file3
#   deleted:    file4
#   deleted:    file5
```

Running `git add -u` will get you to this:

```
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   deleted:    file2
#   deleted:    file3
#   deleted:    file4
#   deleted:    file5
```

And a commit at this point will do the right thing.

Comment: would "git add -A" also be suitable for this?

Comment: hi , you said "And a commit at this point will do the right thing."
But in my case it show error:
Commit failed with error
   0 files committed, 4 files failed to commit: commit deleted files
   unable to index file web/bundles/app
   updating files failed

Comment: Hi @ZainElabidine. You might want to open a new question, since in order to figure out what's going on I would need to see the exact commands you're running and the output of `git status` at various points (and comments really aren't a good place for that).

Answer (score 5):

`git add -u` will update the status of tracked files.

Answer (score 4):

I usually do a commit of the files I made changes to.

If i'd have deleted redundant files, I would do the following after this:

```
git commit -a -m 'deleted redundant files'
```